# Performing a fetch request only on state update

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm new to React and I'm trying to figure out how to work with fetch correctly.
I have a React component that I'd like to update from a remote server whenever its parent's state updated.

i.e - parent's state changed -> myComponent calls remote server and re-renders itself.

I've tried the following:

If I only perform the .`fetch` call on `componentDidMount`, it disregards any state updates.

If I perform the .`fetch` call on `componentDidUpdate` as well it calls the server endlessly (I assume because of some update-render loop)

I have tried using the `componentWillReceiveProps` function, and it works,  but I understand it's now deprecated.
How can I achieve this kind of behavior without `componentWillReceiveProps` ?

```
class myComponent extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  images: []
};
}

componentDidMount() {

let server = "somethingserver.html";
fetch(server)
  .then(res => {
    if (res.ok) {
      return res.json();
    }
    else {
      console.log(res);
      throw new Error(res.statusText);
    }
  })
  .then(
    (result) => {
      this.setState({
        images: result.items
      });
    }
  ).catch(error => console.log(error));
}
componentWillReceiveProps(nextprops) {
if (this.state !== nextprops.state) {
    //same as componentDidMount
    }
}

render() {
 return (
   <Gallery images={this.state.images} enableImageSelection={false} />
);
}
}
```

Comment: your component updates whenever a state or prop update is introduced. what you should probably do is do it in the mount as well as the update under a certain condition.

Comment: Does the fetch depend on any updates from the parent?

Comment: @AnhVo yes, the server address changes according to the parent's state (not included for code brevity)

Comment: @Nielsvandenbroeck - what kind of condition could prevent the endless fetch?

Comment: that depends on when your fetch should happen. Do you want to fetch whenever something specific changes?

Comment: @Nielsvandenbroeck the state basically holds a search term, and the fetch performs that search. if the term changes I'd like to fetch, but currently the fetch happens over and over. (with componentDidUpdate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getDerivedStateFromProps`.  It's the updated version of `componentWillReceiveProps`.

You should also read this, though: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Using props to update internal state in a component can lead to complex bugs and there are often better solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Given our conversation in the comments I can only assume that your search term is in a parent component. So what I recommend you to do is pass it to this component as a prop so you can do the following in your componentDid update:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  const { searchTerm: previousSearch } = prevProps;
  const { searchTerm } = this.props;

  if (searchTerm !== previousSearch) fetch() ....
}
```